# Reading a matrix of numbers from a txt file

Tags: c, matrix, input

So, I created a matrix on a text file, which looks like this:

```
1.0#2.2#3.4
3.4#5.5#1.0
6.6#5.5#1.0
```

I need my script to read each number on the line, add them and then create a new matrix with the result of dividing each number for the sum of the whole line.
Example:

```
1.0+2.2+3.4 = 6.6
```

The first line of the second matrix that I will create will be:

```
0.15#0.33#0.51 (because 1.0/6.6 is 0.15 etc.)
```

Now I can print the whole matrix but I can't get my head on how to save each number of the line as a variable and add it to the next numbers, any suggestion on this?

This is my current work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main() {
    FILE *fptr;
    double c;

    // Open file
    fptr = fopen("mat.txt", "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file \n");
        exit(0);
    }

    // Read contents from file
    c = fgetc(fptr);
    while (c != EOF) {
        printf ("%c", c);
        c = fgetc(fptr);
    }

    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Will your matrix size fixed always(3*3)?

Comment: You need 1/ to read lines (search for `fgets`), then 2/ convert character strings to `double` (search for `strtod`). The tokenization with `strtok` is unnecessary here.

Comment: Yes, for now is a 3x3 fixed matrix @kiranBiradar. I did not think about strtod, thanks sergebellesta!

Comment: Curious: what matrix line would you expect with input like: `"1.0#2.0#-3.0"` or `"0.0#0.0#0.0"` (the sum == 0.0)?

Comment: What do you mean @chux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `matrix` will be of size `3*3` always and `#` is the deliminator, in that case you can use `fscanf` to read 3 values in while loop like below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    double a=0,b=0,c=0;
    double matrix[3][3];

    // Open file
    fptr = fopen("mat.txt", "r");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file \n");
        exit(0);
    }

    int i =0;
   /*fscanf reads the 3 values each time into a,b and c*/
    while (fscanf(fptr,"%lf#%lf#%lf", &a,&b,&c) == 3)
    {
        double sum = a+b+c;
        matrix[i][0] = a/sum;
        matrix[i][1] = b/sum;
        matrix[i][2] = c/sum;
        i++;
    }

    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
     printf ("%lf %lf %lf\n", matrix[i][0],matrix[i][1],matrix[i][2]);

    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up: it may be useful to verify if `sum != 0`.

Comment: The output `printf` format should be `"%f#%f#%f\n"`

Answer (score 0):

Below method uses dynamic memory allocation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    size_t x = 3, y = 3;
    int ret, i, j;
    FILE *fptr_in , *fptr_out;
    double (*d)[y], sum = 0;
    d = malloc( sizeof(double) * x * y );
    assert(d != NULL);
    // Open file
    fptr_in = fopen("mat.txt", "r");
    assert(fptr_in != NULL);

    /*file to write output*/
    fptr_out = fopen("mat_out.txt", "w");
    assert(fptr_out != NULL);

    for(i = 0; i < x; i++){
        sum = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < y; j++){
            ret = fscanf(fptr_in, "%lf", &d[i][j]);
            assert(ret > 0);
            sum += d[i][j];
        }
        for(j = 0; j < x; j++){
            ret = fprintf(fptr_out, "%lf ", d[i][j]/sum);
        }
        fprintf(fptr_out, "\n");
    }
    free(d);
    fclose(fptr_in);
    fclose(fptr_out);
    return 0;
}
```